# Resharper convert auto-property to full property

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, properties, resharper

I found [the opposite here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Convert_Property_to_Auto-Property.html), but I need to frequently change from auto-property to full property - would it be possible to automate that (and with a shortcut perhaps):

### From Auto-Property

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

### To Property with Backing Field

```
    private string _firstName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
        }
    }
```

*Obviously, I would then change the full property further ...*

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Place your cursor on the property name, then wait a second or two. Press the Resharper hotkey sequence (Alt-Enter) and the second option should be "To property with backing field" which is what you want.

Alternatively, you can click the "hammer" icon in the left margin to get the option.

Comment: Nice one! I tried that at first, but it didnt work, and i think the key is to wait a bit!

Comment: You can also click on the property name and click on the hammer icon on the left to get to this option.

Comment: Thanks! I was a little confused that the 'Refactor This...' command didn't give this option, but I guess that is where they split hairs that converting it in place is not technically refactoring maybe?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work (ALT-Enter) you must to configure resharper keyboard schema. VS -> Tools -> Options -> ReSharper -> General -> Options -> Keyboard and menus -> Resharper keyboard Schema -> Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add an extended solution which also allows to create a property in this style, that has support for `INotifyPropertyChanged` for viewmodels:

```
public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set
    {
        if (value == _name) return;
        _name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Raises the <see cref="PropertyChanged"/> event for the given <paramref name="propertyName"/>.
///
/// The <see cref="NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute"/> attribute is used
/// because of Resharper support for "to property with change notification":
/// https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__INotifyPropertyChanged_Support.html
/// </summary>
/// <param name="propertyName"></param>
[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

The required steps are:

- Install the Nuget package "JetBrains.Annotations" in the project were
  your viewmodels are located
- Use the `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]` attribute on the method where the `PropertyChanged` event is raised
- After that, the option "To property with change notification" is available for the properties of your viewmodels

[image]

See also: [Jetbrains INotifyPropertyChanged support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__INotifyPropertyChanged_Support.html)