# Convert auto property to full property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, visual-studio-2013

I often need to convert auto properties to full properties with a backing field so that I can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It gets very tedious when a class has 50+ properties.

```
public string MyProperty { get; set;}
```

to

```
private string _myProperty;
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _myProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        _myProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }
}
```

I was able to create a code snippet that creates a new property in the above format, but I don't know if it is possible to pull in an existing property's name and type and replace it.

I saw [kindofmagic](http://kindofmagic.codeplex.com/) but I really don't want to use arcane magic in my project.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726918/resharper-convert-auto-property-to-full-property) explains how to do it in Resharper, but I don't have Resharper. I even downloaded the trial and still couldn't figure out how to do it.

Is there some way to do this with code snippets, macros, or even a free extension? It seems like it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Well alt+enter didn't do anything because I didn't enable shortcuts and I couldn't find anything useful in the menus. Regardless, that solution would have only lasted 30 days.

Comment: Resharper is pretty useless without shortcuts enabled. Give it a chance next time.

Comment: You can use a nice simple extension called PropMan, very quick and works both ways, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OlegShilo.PropMan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have notepad++, you could do it via RegEx (quite ugly, but works)

Find what: `(public)\s+([a-zA-z0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-z0-9]+)\s*\{\s*+get;\s*set;\s*\}`

Replace with: `private \2  _\3\; \r\n \1 \2 \3 \r\n \{ \r\n get \{ return _\3\; \} \r\n set \{ _\3=value\; OnPropertyChanged\(\"\3\"\)\; \} \r\n \}`

Make sure "Regular Expression" is checked

This is what the Find/Replace screen looks like:
[image: FindReplaceImg]

And it goes from

[image: StartImg]

To:

[image: EndImg]

Edit: Thanks to Britton, here is the Visual Studio equivalent:

Find: `public[^\S\r\n](.+)[^\S\r\n](\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b)[^\S\r\n]{[^\S\r\n]get;[‌​^\S\r\n]set;[^\S\r\n]}`

Replace: `private $1 _$2;\r\npublic $1 $2 {\r\nget\r\n{\r\nreturn _$2;\r\n}\r\nset\r\n{\r\n_$2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("$2");\r\n}\r\n}`

Comment: maybe that same regex also works with Visual Studio's own find/replace? The syntax might be slightly different, but it should work.

Comment: Not the most convenient but it does work. I'll accept it as the answer if no one comes up with anything better. I was able to convert the regex for Visual Studio at least. Find: `public[^\S\r\n](.+)[^\S\r\n](\b(_\w+|[\w-[0-9_]]\w*)\b)[^\S\r\n]{[^\S\r\n]get;[^\S\r\n]set;[^\S\r\n]}` Replace: `private $1 _$2;\r\npublic $1 $2 {\r\nget\r\n{\r\nreturn _$2;\r\n}\r\nset\r\n{\r\n_$2 = value; OnPropertyChanged("$2");\r\n}\r\n}`

Comment: Dan's regex find and replace won't pick up properties with generics in the type, eg `public IList<Event> Events { get; set; }` or nullable value types, eg `public int? ...` .  The angle brackets and question mark throw it out.  A minor modification fixes that: `(public)\s+([a-zA-z0-9<>\?]+)\s+([a-zA-z0-9]+)\s*\{\s*+get;\s*set;\s*\}`.  (the only change is the addition of the angle brackets and question mark, from `(public)\s+([a-zA-z0-9]+)\s+...` to `(public)\s+([a-zA-z0-9<>\?]+)\s+...`.)

Comment: Another change, to handle square brackets, eg `public byte[] ...`.  Now the first regex becomes: `(public)\s+([a-zA-z0-9<>\[\]\?]+)\s+([a-zA-z0-9]+)\s*\{\s*+get;\s*set;\s*\}`.  The only change from Dan's regex is the addition of the `<>\[\]\?`.

Comment: Dear Lord at that answer... props!

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using [Dan's regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23368996/682081) for the conversion of many properties at once. I also found a Visual Studio extension called [PropMan](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/64c1ba9d-42fb-4f0a-9c81-1e730a6df0b1) that is good for converting a single property at a time. Just put the cursor on the property then hit `Ctrl+\, Ctrl+\` to convert between auto/full.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it looks like these type of custom refactoring snippets aren't supported in Visual Studio. Looking through the documentation I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171442%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> SurroundsWith: allows the code snippet to be placed around a selected
>   piece of code.
>
> Expansion: allows the code snippet to be inserted at the cursor.
>
> Refactoring: specifies that the code snippet is used during Visual C#
>   refactoring. **Refactoring cannot be used in custom code snippets.**

I also went ahead and created a snippet for creating a full property from scratch, but it's only for new properties, not existing ones.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>fprop</Title>
      <Shortcut>fprop</Shortcut>
      <Description>Full Property with Backing Store</Description>
      <Author>Nathan McGinn</Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Refactoring</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>type</ID>
          <Default>string</Default>
          <ToolTip>The type of your property</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>back</ID>
          <Default>_myProperty</Default>
          <ToolTip>The name of your backing variable</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>prop</ID>
          <Default>MyProperty</Default>
          <ToolTip>Your public property's name</ToolTip>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="CSharp">
        <![CDATA[private $type$ $back$;
        public $type$ $prop$
        {
          get
          {
            return this.$back$;
          }
          set
          {
            this.$back$ = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("$prop$");
          }
        }]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

I think that's as far as snippets go, a Visual Studio extension will be required to refactor the existing code (or a regex find/replace as Dan suggested).

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this code with the `class1` only. But, it will give you starting point. I've not used fancy naming for the variables. Please change variable names as appropriate. It'll put the `private...` in front of the properties and ignore the methods.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
 public class Class1
 {        
    public int Val
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Val1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void M1() { }
  }
}
```

code that change the above class

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Class1 c = new Class1();
        Type testType = c.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] prinfo = testType.GetProperties();
        string[] filetest=File.ReadAllLines("Class1.cs"); //put correct file path here
        int index=0,i=0;            
        foreach (PropertyInfo p in prinfo)
        {                
            while(i < filetest.Length )
            {
                index = filetest[i].IndexOf(p.Name);
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    index = 0;
                    filetest[i]=filetest[i].Insert(0, "private " + p.PropertyType.ToString() + " _" + p.Name+";" + Environment.NewLine);
                }
                i++;
            }                  

        }
        File.WriteAllLines("Class1.cs", filetest);//put correct file path here
        Console.Read();
    }        
}
```